# How do I make my livewire store method send data using POST, seems it is using a GET method

Tags: laravel-livewire

```
public function storeProject()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $fileName = $this->files->store('uploads');

        Project::create([
            'title' => $this->title,
            'description' => $this->description,
            'files' => $fileName,
            'skills' => $this->skills,
        ]);

        session()->flash('message', 'Your Project has been posted Successfully!');
    }
```

My View

```
@section('title', 'Post a job')
<div>
    <div class="py-12 font-sans">
        <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="m-4 p-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-800 via-blue-700 to-blue-600 text-white rounded-md">
                <h2 class="text-4xl">Tell us what you need done!</h2>
                <p class="break-words mt-5">Within minutes, get in touch with knowledgeable independent contractors. View
                    their profiles, give them feedback, look at their portfolios, and talk with them. Only pay the
                    freelancer once you are completely satisfied with their job.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{-- Form is located here --}}
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="title">Choose a Title for your Project</label>
                        <input type="title" id="title" name="title" wire:model.lazy="title"
                            placeholder="e.g. Build me a website">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="message">Tells more about your project</label>
                        <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="4" wire:model.lazy="description"
                            placeholder="Describe your project here..." maxlength="4000"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="user_avatar">Upload file</label>
                        <input wire:model="files" aria-describedby="user_avatar_help" id="user_avatar" name="files"
                            type="file">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-6">
                        <label for="skills">
                            What skills are required</label>
                        <p class="break-words mt-2">Enter up to 5 skills that best describe your project. Freelancers
                            will use these skills to find projects they are most interested and experienced in.</p>
                        <input type="text" id="skills" name="skills" data-role="tags-input"
                            wire:model.lazy="skills" placeholder="Enter skills here separated by commas...">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" wire:click="storeProject">
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After clicking on submit, this is my url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-project?title=Iphone+XR+Mini+Updated&description=I+need+it&files=Gilles+Ashley%27s+CV.pdf&skills=Mysql%2C+C%2B%2B+etc`. What is wrong with my codes please? Any help?
After clicking on submit, this is my url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-project?title=Iphone+XR+Mini+Updated&description=I+need+it&files=Gilles+Ashley%27s+CV.pdf&skills=Mysql%2C+C%2B%2B+etc`. What is wrong with my codes please? Any help?
After clicking on submit, this is my url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-project?title=Iphone+XR+Mini+Updated&description=I+need+it&files=Gilles+Ashley%27s+CV.pdf&skills=Mysql%2C+C%2B%2B+etc`. This is my blade code.
After clicking on submit, this is my url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-project?title=Iphone+XR+Mini+Updated&description=I+need+it&files=Gilles+Ashley%27s+CV.pdf&skills=Mysql%2C+C%2B%2B+etc`. What is wrong with my codes please? Any help?
After clicking on submit, this is my url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-project?title=Iphone+XR+Mini+Updated&description=I+need+it&files=Gilles+Ashley%27s+CV.pdf&skills=Mysql%2C+C%2B%2B+etc`. What is wrong with my codes please? Any help?
After clicking on submit, this is my url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post-project?title=Iphone+XR+Mini+Updated&description=I+need+it&files=Gilles+Ashley%27s+CV.pdf&skills=Mysql%2C+C%2B%2B+etc`. What is wrong with my codes please? Any help?

Comment: Can you post the component view? Will be easier to help with all the pieces to the puzzle. I'm going to say the issue is within your component view.

Comment: I have pasted the view codes up there please, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the form tag and the submit button:

```php
<form wire:submit.prevent="storeProject">

<button type="submit">
 Submit
</button>
```

This will take care of the page refresh and the `GET` call. You do not need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when using Livewire.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have created a controller function `storeProject()` and a blade view with your `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` which is completely wrong. Check here how livewire should work https://laracasts.com/

Comment: Alright I'll check that. Thank you.